# How to get href attribute for link with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery. I have link like this ..

```
<div>title 1<a href="/delete/1" class="del">Delete</a></div>
<div>title 2<a href="/delete/2" class="del">Delete</a></div>
```

jquery

```
  $(".del").click(function () {
     alert($(this).attr('href'));
     event.preventDefault();
  });
```

I am trying to get href attribute. But it says Object object. I am trying to figure out what I doing wrong. How I can fix this.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Though you have wrong `preventDefault()` call, your code should work.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I dont get the Object Object ..check here http://jsfiddle.net/GNYP4/ ..

Comment: What you have should work - although you need to pass `event` to handler function: http://jsfiddle.net/AVPf7/

Comment: Except for the event.preventDefault() (as noted by others), your code should work. Only thing I could think is that: maybe jQuery conflicts with something else? (do you have a variable named $ or similiar things?) Maybe take a look at jQuery.noConflict() (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) an try using "jQuery" instead of "$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
alert($(this).prop('href'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
alert($(this).prop('href'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that's wrong in your snippet is that you're referencing an `event` variable, that is not declared.

This work for me:

```js
$(".del").click(function (event) {
 alert($(this).attr('href'));
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>title 1<a href="/delete/1" class="del">Delete</a></div>
<div>title 2<a href="/delete/2" class="del">Delete</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the comments and suggested answers I tried to isolate your issue using a single HTML page like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.del').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>title 1<a href="/delete/1" class="del">Delete</a></div>
<div>title 2<a href="/delete/2" class="del">Delete</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When testing this the code works perfectly fine. I also compared the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) vs the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to see why people are suggesting this answer. Take careful note of the documentation of these 2 since swapping out one with the other isn't really problem solving for this case. The question author needs to provide a more specific testcase where the error occurs so we can provide a conclusive answer.